# Couchbase increase number of vbuckets in a bucket

Tags: couchbase

I have a questions about couchbase bucket.
Is there anyway to change the number of vbuckets of a bucket. By default, it is 1024.
Anyone know, pls tell me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

vBuckets are an internal representation of Buckets (and are not visible to the application) that allow Couchbase to shard data evenly across the cluster. The quantity of vBuckets is not configurable, but also is factored into the key hashing algorithm that determines which vBucket a k/v pair lives on (which is why it isn't configurable). Is there a reason you wanted to change this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues trying to do cbrestore between environments (say Linux to Mac) due to the difference in vbuckets (linux has 1024, mac has 64 or 256), then read this article:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#couchbase-backup-restore

Specifically, use the memcached protocol instead:

```
cbrestore /linuxbackup/today memcached://mac:11211 -b default -B default
```